# Docker Dev Environment: files created in build process are lost when opening in VSCode

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-desktop, devenv

To be clear: I'm talking about the Docker-Desktop feature "Dev Environments". See [here](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/dev-environments/).

I think I'm missing something about the build process of Docker DevEnv. When I build my DevEnv I can see in the logs that `npm install` is running and necessary files get created. I can even see them when inspecting the container files. But when opening the DevEnv in VS Code a new container gets created overriding the old one and thus deleting all files created in the build process.

## Detailed explanation

I want to run Node.js in a Docker DevEnv and work inside it with VS Code. I have a really simple setup with a `compose-dev.yaml` file that looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    platform: linux/arm64
    build:
      context: .
      target: runner
    entrypoint:
      - sleep
      - infinity
    ports:
      - 1234:1234
```

And a `Dockerfile` that looks like this:

```
# development builder (faster than runner, do heavy tasks in here!)
FROM node:20 AS development

WORKDIR "/com.docker.devenvironments.code"

COPY . .

RUN npm install



# development runner (ARM/M1 compatible)
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:20 AS runner

COPY --from=development . .
```

The 2 stage build process is because I work on an M1 chip. I think this is not related to my problem.

When I setup the DevEnv in Docker-Desktop I can see in the logs that `npm install` is running as declared in the `Dockerfile`.
[`npm install` running in build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiN72.png)

When inspecting the new container I can see the newly generated `node_modules/` folder.
[generated files are present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChfdE.png)

But when clicking "Open in VSCode" Docker seems to create a new container overriding the old one.
[new container started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9bYD.png)

The new container kinda overrides the old one and all the generated files are now lost.
[`node_modules/` missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8Nkp.png)

So I don't think this is a bug but im getting sth wrong here. I don't know why I should specify anything in the `Dockerfile` if it's getting deleted anyways. When opening "normal" Docker containers in VSCode this doesn't happen.

I would expect that opening the DevEnv in VSCode is not overriding every change made in the build process of my DevEnv.